# The difference between Gdiplus::Image and Gdiplus::Bitmap

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, gdi+

I was converting PNG files to JPG format,my codes like below:

```
Gdiplus::Image *img = Imgae::FromFile("my.png");
img.Save("your.jpg", encoder, param);
```

The jpg file I got was SO fuzzy that I couldn't distinguish.So I tried again like this:

```
Bitmap bmp(w, h);
Graphics g(&bmp);
g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
bmp.Save("your.jpg", encoder, param);
```

Miracle happened, dest file was so clear and smaller than previous one in bytes.
I don't know why two dest files were so different?

Comment: I think save doesn't have ability to convert or having issue in GDI+. to confirm this do following.
1) Can you create graphics object using Image instead of Bitmap.
2) DrawImage using graphics and save.
Then you will notice that is problem with Image or limitation of Save functionality?